# OpenGL Viewport not working

Tags: c, opengl, viewport

I have a 3D labyrinth with a 3d model that the user controls to exit the labyrinth. I want to put a minimap in a viewport on the bottom right of the window. Except the map isn't going to the viewport, it's drawing at 0,0.
Here is the code to draw the minimap:

```
GLfloat SCREEN_WIDTH = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
GLfloat SCREEN_HEIGHT = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glViewport(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2, 0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-40, 40, -40, 40);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glCallList(modelo.labirinto[JANELA_NAVIGATE]);
//glCallList(modelo.chao[JANELA_NAVIGATE]);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: maybe 0, 0 isn't where you expect it to be, try height and width of /2 while keeping the offset

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to call `glTranslatef()` to specify the position of the drawing after:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: I thought that by using a viewport, it would automatically draw on the viewport